# Process console output not redirecting

Tags: c#, wpf, process, console, output

I am trying to execute a console/batch application from a `BackgroundWorker` in C# WPF application and show the output in a text box.

The batch application is as follows:

```
@echo off
echo start
"D:\openjdk-1.7.0-u40\bin\javac.exe"
echo finish
```

My C# code is:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\exec.bat";
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(delegate(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, System.Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
});

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I have also tried using this to read the console stream:

```
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, System.Environment.NewLine + output);
```

In my output, it displays `start` and `finish`, but no output from javac.exe, whereas if I run the batch file myself from cmd.exe it does.

How can I make the output of javac.exe appear?

Comment: Is the output from javac successful output? Or is it an error? It might be worth using RedirectStandardError as well.

Comment: javac just displays it's commandline options as I didn't provide any. But I have tried that, along with `process.BeginErrorReadLine();`

Comment: Placing the code in your question into a simple console application with a BackgroundWorker works for me if I have a batch file calling java.exe (I don't have javac, only the jre). I get start, java command line options, finish. Have you tried calling something other than javac? Or moved javac into a different folder temporarily?

Comment: I did end up finding a solution for this, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `process.Start();` I added the following code to successfully produce an output:

```
do
{
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    buildWorker.ReportProgress(0, System.Environment.NewLine + output);
}
while (!process.HasExited);
```

Answer (score 0):

Start *javac.exe* with parameter:

```
@echo off
echo start
start "D:\openjdk-1.7.0-u40\bin\javac.exe" /?
echo finish
```

Comment: Still doesnt output to the text box